# Even after installed isight firmware for my macbook pro, webcam is not reconize

Tags: webcam, macbook-pro

This happened after I installed nvidia drivers to debug problem of pause and wakeup computer. So, too resume situation:

- macbook pro 5,3 with ubuntu 17.10
- before nvidia, webcam OK
- after nvidia, webcam out of order
- /dev/video* disapeared
- lsusb give: Bus 001 Device 003: ID    05ac:8507 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight
- I see nothing about camera with dmesg or lspci

Thank's for help

Comment: Did you ever get this webcam working?